# Is it possible to evaluate this indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, functional-calculus

Evaluate the Indefinite Integral:

$$\int \sqrt{x - \sin(x)}\,dx
$$

My attempt:  I tried using Hypergeometric Functions but it doesn't seem to be of any help....

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is useful reference

Comment: @marshal craft thank you so much

Comment: Also i can find that integrands of form $\sqrt{a-sin(x)}$ are not with elementary functions except when $a=1$. I think your question is weaker case of it?

Comment: @marshal craft i see

Comment: @marshal craft you are considering a, but here is x. There must be a way using Hypergeometric Series

Comment: I could be wrong, i was just noting a similar expression for which it is not integrable, not sure why upvoted. Sorry.

Comment: I think the case $\sqrt{a-sin(x)}$ means it is not integrable except for $x=1$ at that point alone. Which im not sure by definition of integration if that makes sense to itnegrate at a single point, but then the indefinite integral as well should be defined though as solution to $\int {1-sin(x)} dx$.

Comment: For if we think of it as a 3 dimensional surface $f(x,y)=\sqrt{y-sin(x)}$ may help.

Comment: @marshal craft 3 dimension will require limits i guess...well definite integration is valid for this.....

Comment: Yeah im not sure it even helps, now. I'll refrain from commenting with guesses, I apologize. Interesting question though.

Comment: @marshal craft no need to apologize...here in stack exchange we all are friends

Comment: It is very hard or impossible since the well know indefinite $
\int {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx} 
$ hasn't a closed form so yours (which is) $
\int {\sqrt x \sqrt {1 - \frac{{\sin x}}{x}} dx} $. How about bounds?

Comment: @mwomath I want it without any limits

Comment: I don't know if this works (but I don't think so) I transformed it into two forms
1- $
\int {\sqrt {\frac{{\sin ^{ - 1} u - u}}{{1 - u^2 }}} du} $ or 2- $ 
\int {\sqrt {2\arctan \left( u \right) - \frac{{2u}}{{1 + u^2 }}} \frac{2}{{1 + u^2 }}du} 
$

Comment: @mwomath I am getting dollar sign and other weird symbols...The text is illegible

Comment: 1- Assume $x=\sin^{-1}u$ or 2- $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ with $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$ integrate both sides to get $x$.

Comment: @mwomath I don't think it helps...Please confirm and then post a proper answer....

Comment: How about previous comments. It is OK. no more comment.

Comment: @mwomath Sorry, you can comment but actually i am using Android App to view it...So all dollar sign is becoming visible and text is not clear...

Comment: @mwomath I guess maybe a bug caused it....In web i can view ur suggestions properly

Comment: He probably miss typed it then edited it and fixed it. If there is a syntax error the browser will just show $ and symbols as text.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+sqrt(x+-+sin(x))) comes up empty for this. It is likely that a closed form for the antiderivative doesn't exist.

Comment: @marshal craft Yes

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I can prove that the integral exists, only what i need is some generalization

Comment: That's not the question to decide if integrable or not? Proving would give an answer, no?

Comment: Yes, you can prove that the integral exists. The integrand is continuous, so it is certainly integrable. But that is not the question asked. You are asking for an expression for it. I find it highly unlikely that you will find a nice closed form expression. You could can produce infinite series that will converge to it over finite intervals, but you are likely not going to find some expression in terms of a finite number of operations on known functions whose derivative is $\sqrt{x + \sin x}$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair Maybe but series expansion shows a pattern and it looks like integrable...

Comment: @marshal craft yes but I believe it's is someway possible

Comment: @marshal craft all we need is generalization of series...if no such function exists so what?? Cant we generalize?

Comment: Yes you can convert it to hypergeometric using the sqrt() series expansion but then you have F(xxx;sin(x)/x) and you would need to integrate that against sqrt(x)*dx which I don't see as an improvement.  And the series expansion is restricted away from the origin, but accepting branch points one might analytically continue it as function.  Actually, I think you are stuck with Elliptic functions and mappings; but none of the simple transforms look likely.

Comment: @rrogers What about Puiseux Series?

Comment: @rrogers See i am getting a pattern using Puiseux Series, but I am facing difficulty in generalizing the constant coefficients

Comment: For answering if it has elementary indefinite integral I think you may consider working with risch algorithm to find out. The case I said earlier, I can't seem to show that it shows anything as the case when constant is $x$ is different.

Comment: I was thinking integration by parts would get a $\int {\sqrt{a-sin(x)}} dx$ term but can't get it.

Comment: @marshal craft Yes by parts won't work

Comment: @marshalcraft The Puiseux series is interesting, but I am not competent to deal with it.  There is one thing though: we can observe that (x-sin(x)) merely drops the first term of sin(x) expansion.  Since the series is periodic various derivatives, say with introduced variables, might yield Elliptic integral functions.   And no I can't reliably expand on that :)  But consider y=a*x and differentiate the integral with respect to a; then you have a function of (cos(a*x)-1)^(1/2) which superficially looks like an Elliptic integral.  Total disclaimer if you quote this.

Comment: @rrogers Is it of first kind elliptical integral?

Comment: Okay! I have to do some research here.  The last comment didn't quite work.  There is a very old explicit elementary paper (around 1900) that gave very clear instructions about how to reduce some integrals to Elliptic ones.  I saved it somewhere on my disks, and have to find it and read it again.  It might or might not work.

Comment: @rrogers no worries, it will either be first or second kind for sure